# Android Studio fails to install update (error : Failed to read or create install properties file.)

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-2.3, android-update-sdk

**Screenshot of error**

[image]

I am running [ Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o] on Ubuntu 16.04. From last few days android studio gives me error on trying to update. I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

I ran the Android studio as administrator and then it worked as it is a permission issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I seem always to forget setting AS to run as an administrator after each installation on a Windows PC.

Comment: or `sudo` if you're on command line: cd into $ANDROID_HOME$/sdk/tools/bin and `sudo bash sdkmanager "platforms;android-26" "build-tools;26.0.1"`

Comment: On Windows I manually had to create an empty repositories.cfg inside c:\users\me\.android

Comment: For Windows 10 to always run as administrator: 1- go to the startup location (something like C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio) 2- right-click the shortcut 3- select 'Troubleshoot Compatibility' 4- tick the box next to 'The application requires additional permissions' 5- click 'Test the program' (the program will start and the administrator confirmation dialog will appear) 6- after confirming, go back to the compatibility troubleshooter and click 'Next' 7- select 'Yes, save these settings for this program'. Now it will always run as administrator.

Answer (score 69):

`chmod 777 $ANDROID_HOME -R` This is not a good solution like @spark mentioned.

I solved this issue by setting the ownership to myself

`sudo chown $USER:$USER $ANDROID_HOME -R`

Comment: You should not change the directory ownership unless you have installed the SDK in that user's directory. Invoking `sudo chown` tells me otherwise.

Comment: `sudo chown $USER: $ANDROID_HOME -R` should be enough

Comment: This worked for me, and I replaced the deprecated `$ANDROID_HOME` with `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

Comment: Changing the group instead of the owner and using `g=u` as permission might be a less invasive option. Making all files executable is not a very good idea.

Comment: On OSX, this command worked for me: `sudo chown -R $USER: $ANDROID_HOME`. The `-R` had to be moved at the front.

Answer (score 26):

Problem Solved!

The permission of my Android directory was set to write only by root so android-studio was unable to write any changes. I changed the permissions to 777 and it fixed the problem.

Thanks for Help anyways.

Comment: how to set permission of that folder?

Comment: link to set permissions https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-and-get-full-access-to-files-and-folders-in-windows-10/

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution. Setting such permissions is a security problem.

Comment: As stated by some people here already, setting folder permissions (and sub-folders using `-R`) to 777 is like saying "OK guys, this is free for all now!". The accepted solution should be the one proposed by [@SAJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382514/3672398)

Comment: `777` will make all files executable. Why not use `go=u` or `ugo=rwX` instead?

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1:**

Use: `sudo chown $USER: $ANDROID_HOME -R`

My solution is setting folder permissions (and sub-folders using -R).

**Root cause:**

The permission of my Android SDK directory was set to write only by root so android-studio was unable to write any changes.

**Detailed Process:**

Take $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools for example:

```
sudo chown $USER: $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Before executing the command line:

[image: before executing the sudo chown]

```
bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 .
drwx------@ 104 gongzelong  staff   3328 Nov  6 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff  18436 Oct 26 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 gongzelong  staff     64 Nov  4 01:47 .downloadIntermediates
-rw-r--r--    1 gongzelong  staff     16 Nov  6 17:46 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   41 gongzelong  staff   1312 Nov  4 23:08 .temp
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff   1158 Aug 30  2018 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Aug 29  2016 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x@  34 gongzelong  staff   1088 Nov  3 01:47 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 cmake
drwxr-xr-x@  51 gongzelong  staff   1632 Oct 24  2016 docs
drwxr-xr-x   17 root        wheel    544 Nov 12  2019 emulator
drwxr-xr-x@   8 gongzelong  staff    256 Jul 31  2018 extras
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gongzelong  staff     96 Nov  7  2017 fonts
drwxr-xr-x@   9 gongzelong  staff    288 Apr 21  2020 licenses
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 lldb
drwxr-xr-x    7 gongzelong  staff    224 Nov  4 22:47 ndk
drwxr-xr-x@  20 gongzelong  staff    640 Sep 29  2018 ndk-bundle
drwxr-xr-x@   5 gongzelong  staff    160 Dec 15  2016 patcher
**drwxr-xr-x   19 root        wheel    608 Nov 12  2019 platform-tools**
drwxr-xr-x@  16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  33 gongzelong  staff   1056 Feb 17  2020 skins
drwxr-xr-x@  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Nov  3 01:51 sources
drwxr-xr-x@  13 gongzelong  staff    416 Apr  8  2019 system-images
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Feb  4  2018 temp
drwxr-xr-x   15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 26 21:18 tools
```

After executing the command line:

[image: after executing the sudo chown]

```
➜  bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 .
drwx------@ 104 gongzelong  staff   3328 Nov  6 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff  18436 Oct 26 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 gongzelong  staff     64 Nov  4 01:47 .downloadIntermediates
-rw-r--r--    1 gongzelong  staff     16 Nov  6 17:46 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   41 gongzelong  staff   1312 Nov  4 23:08 .temp
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff   1158 Aug 30  2018 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Aug 29  2016 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x@  34 gongzelong  staff   1088 Nov  3 01:47 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 cmake
drwxr-xr-x@  51 gongzelong  staff   1632 Oct 24  2016 docs
drwxr-xr-x   17 root        wheel    544 Nov 12  2019 emulator
drwxr-xr-x@   8 gongzelong  staff    256 Jul 31  2018 extras
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gongzelong  staff     96 Nov  7  2017 fonts
drwxr-xr-x@   9 gongzelong  staff    288 Apr 21  2020 licenses
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 lldb
drwxr-xr-x    7 gongzelong  staff    224 Nov  4 22:47 ndk
drwxr-xr-x@  20 gongzelong  staff    640 Sep 29  2018 ndk-bundle
drwxr-xr-x@   5 gongzelong  staff    160 Dec 15  2016 patcher
**drwxr-xr-x   19 gongzelong  wheel    608 Nov 12  2019 platform-tools**
drwxr-xr-x@  16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  33 gongzelong  staff   1056 Feb 17  2020 skins
drwxr-xr-x@  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Nov  3 01:51 sources
drwxr-xr-x@  13 gongzelong  staff    416 Apr  8  2019 system-images
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Feb  4  2018 temp
drwxr-xr-x   15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 26 21:18 tools
```

Then we do the update in SDK management:
[image: Before update]

[image: updaing the sdk 1]

[image: updaing the sdk 2]

[image: update successfully]

before and after install sdk result screenshot

[image: before and after install result screenshot]

**Solution 2:**

Run Android Studio as administration.

`sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 4.1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

It could also install the android sdk update successfully

[image: before updating]
[image: update successfully]
[image: check and confirm the result]

Answer (score 4):

for macos:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/Library/Android
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me :) yay..!

Comment: This will only work if your `ANDROID_HOME` is `~/Library/Android`  — and 777 is a bit over the top. `g=u` (set group to user) might be a less invasive option.

Comment: Just look for a directory with wrong permissions and `chown` it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Delete old version
2. Reboot
3. Install new version

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a *nix system, you should locate `$ANDROID_HOME`. Mine is installed inside `/opt`. Given that this directory belongs to `root`, you will need to invoke `sudo` before running your command.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues on windows and the problem for me was where the SDK was related.

When you go to `File` - `Project Structure` - `Android SDK Location` you can see what SDK directory is defined.
The default SDK location was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` and it seems you need to be an Administrator to be able to download packages.

I changed it to my user directory so I don't need admin privileges and I was able to download the required packages without any problems.

Also make sure you accpeted all licences before.

Comment: Running Android Studio with administrator privileges worked for my case.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to update the platform-tools and emulators. What I found was there was an .installer directory in each of those directories. Deleting those allowed the update to complete.

[image: Rogue .installer directory in platform-tools]

[image: Rogue .installer directory in emulator]

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I tried any other solution regarding fixing permissions but nothing solved my error. But deleting those ".installer" directories solved it finally.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this issue and when I navigated to the existing install of the SDK I found that it was symlinked to a previous version that I installed using Homebrew (which is no longer supported).

The fix was to remove this symlink, then Android Studio was able to install the updated SDK as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I solved it by first enabling the "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..." setting in the SDK Manager Tools > Options menu. and then I opened Android Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when I tried to install new packages using SDK Manager in the Android command line tool.

**Error:** failed to read or create install properties file in SDK manager.

The problem occurred because the SDK manager cannot figure out how to validate licenses without administrator permissions.

**Solution**: Run the command line as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on linux by running `sudo chown /opt/android-sdk` Change    `/opt/android-sdk` to the path of your android sdk

Answer (score 0):

I had a fresh Installation of Android Studio. I ran the install script with root access the first time so my SDK files went buggy and the next time I opened Android Studio, It opened with regular user permissions and I was unable to update the SDK.

I just **deleted** the initial SDK folder and let the studio download it again and the problem was gone.

Answer (score -3):

In windows, you may run Android Studio as **Administrator**

Comment: The OP is running Ubuntu, and randomly running programs with elevated permissions is never a good idea