# Android Studio 4.1.0 could not update SDK (Error: Failed to read or create install properties file)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

**Problem:**

[image: error screenshot]

```
Packages to install: 
- Android SDK Platform 29 (platforms;android-29)
- Android Emulator (emulator)
- Android SDK Platform-Tools (platform-tools)

Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.1.5)".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 30.0.5)".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Failed packages:
 - Android SDK Platform 29 (platforms;android-29)
 - Android Emulator (emulator)
 - Android SDK Platform-Tools (platform-tools)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

**Background:**

Check Network:
Clash is connected and I could visit google.com via Chrome on Mac

`export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:7890 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7890`

[image]
[image]
[image]

I read the question:
[Android Studio fails to install update (error : Failed to read or create install properties file.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042032/android-studio-fails-to-install-update-error-failed-to-read-or-create-install)

On Mac, it seems that Android Studio already has the admin permission.

Android Studio permission

```
ls -la /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 4.1.0.app/Contents/MacOS
total 128
drwxrwxr-x@  3 gongzelong  admin     96 Sep 24 04:21 .
drwxrwxr-x@ 12 gongzelong  admin    384 Sep 24 04:40 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 gongzelong  admin  65312 Sep 24 04:21 studio
```

sdkmanager permission:

```
ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
total 128
drwxr-xr-x  11 gongzelong  staff   352 Jul 29  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 gongzelong  staff   480 Oct 26 21:18 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  6742 Jul 29  2018 apkanalyzer
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  5253 Jul 29  2018 archquery
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  6040 Jul 29  2018 avdmanager
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  5250 Jul 29  2018 jobb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  6834 Jul 29  2018 lint
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  3323 Jul 29  2018 monkeyrunner
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  5613 Jul 29  2018 screenshot2
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 gongzelong  staff  6047 Jul 29  2018 sdkmanager
-rwxr-xr-x   1 gongzelong  staff  3076 Jul 29  2018 uiautomatorviewer
```

android sdk directory permission:

```
ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 .
drwx------@ 104 gongzelong  staff   3328 Nov  6 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff  18436 Oct 26 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 gongzelong  staff     64 Nov  4 01:47 .downloadIntermediates
-rw-r--r--    1 gongzelong  staff     16 Nov  6 17:46 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   41 gongzelong  staff   1312 Nov  4 23:08 .temp
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff   1158 Aug 30  2018 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Aug 29  2016 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x@  34 gongzelong  staff   1088 Nov  3 01:47 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 cmake
drwxr-xr-x@  51 gongzelong  staff   1632 Oct 24  2016 docs
drwxr-xr-x   17 root        wheel    544 Nov 12  2019 emulator
drwxr-xr-x@   8 gongzelong  staff    256 Jul 31  2018 extras
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gongzelong  staff     96 Nov  7  2017 fonts
drwxr-xr-x@   9 gongzelong  staff    288 Apr 21  2020 licenses
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 lldb
drwxr-xr-x    7 gongzelong  staff    224 Nov  4 22:47 ndk
drwxr-xr-x@  20 gongzelong  staff    640 Sep 29  2018 ndk-bundle
drwxr-xr-x@   5 gongzelong  staff    160 Dec 15  2016 patcher
drwxr-xr-x   19 root        wheel    608 Nov 12  2019 platform-tools
drwxr-xr-x@  16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  33 gongzelong  staff   1056 Feb 17  2020 skins
drwxr-xr-x@  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Nov  3 01:51 sources
drwxr-xr-x@  13 gongzelong  staff    416 Apr  8  2019 system-images
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Feb  4  2018 temp
drwxr-xr-x   15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 26 21:18 tools
```

platforms permission:

```
➜  bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/platforms
total 24
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 gongzelong  staff  10244 Dec  3  2018 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 gongzelong  staff    416 Dec  3  2018 android-16
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 gongzelong  staff    384 Dec 16  2016 android-19
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 gongzelong  staff    384 Dec 18  2016 android-21
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 gongzelong  staff    384 Dec  8  2016 android-22
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 gongzelong  staff    448 Oct 19  2016 android-23
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 19  2016 android-24
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 gongzelong  staff    448 Dec 16  2016 android-25
drwxr-xr-x@ 14 gongzelong  staff    448 Sep 28  2017 android-26
drwxr-xr-x  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Jul 30  2018 android-27
drwxr-xr-x  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Mar 29  2019 android-28
drwxr-xr-x  14 root        staff    448 Nov 12  2019 android-29
drwxr-xr-x  15 gongzelong  staff    480 Nov  3 01:47 android-30
drwxr-xr-x  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Apr 24  2019 android-Q
```

$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

```
➜  bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
total 22584
drwxr-xr-x  19 root        wheel      608 Nov 12  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 26 gongzelong  staff      832 Nov  3 01:51 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root        wheel   274638 Nov 12  2019 NOTICE.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel  3552684 Nov 12  2019 adb
drwxr-xr-x   4 root        wheel      128 Nov 12  2019 api
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel    60544 Nov 12  2019 dmtracedump
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel  1581128 Nov 12  2019 e2fsdroid
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel   309988 Nov 12  2019 etc1tool
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel  1785900 Nov 12  2019 fastboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel    17480 Nov 12  2019 hprof-conv
drwxr-xr-x   3 root        wheel       96 Nov 12  2019 lib64
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel   242532 Nov 12  2019 make_f2fs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel   829668 Nov 12  2019 mke2fs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel     1170 Nov 12  2019 mke2fs.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root        wheel    17783 Nov 12  2019 package.xml
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel  1532436 Nov 12  2019 sload_f2fs
-rw-r--r--   1 root        wheel       38 Nov 12  2019 source.properties
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root        wheel  1315132 Nov 12  2019 sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x   6 root        wheel      192 Nov 12  2019 systrace
```

I open the Android Studio icon in the Dock, does it mean that I run the AS as administrator?

I could download ndk and here is my current sdk:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Use: `sudo chown $USER: $ANDROID_HOME -R`

My solution is setting folder permissions (and sub-folders using -R).

**Root cause:**

The permission of my Android SDK directory was set to write only by root so android-studio was unable to write any changes.

**Detailed Process:**

Take $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools for example:

```
sudo chown $USER: $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Before executing the command line:

[image: before executing the sudo chown]

```
bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 .
drwx------@ 104 gongzelong  staff   3328 Nov  6 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff  18436 Oct 26 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 gongzelong  staff     64 Nov  4 01:47 .downloadIntermediates
-rw-r--r--    1 gongzelong  staff     16 Nov  6 17:46 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   41 gongzelong  staff   1312 Nov  4 23:08 .temp
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff   1158 Aug 30  2018 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Aug 29  2016 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x@  34 gongzelong  staff   1088 Nov  3 01:47 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 cmake
drwxr-xr-x@  51 gongzelong  staff   1632 Oct 24  2016 docs
drwxr-xr-x   17 root        wheel    544 Nov 12  2019 emulator
drwxr-xr-x@   8 gongzelong  staff    256 Jul 31  2018 extras
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gongzelong  staff     96 Nov  7  2017 fonts
drwxr-xr-x@   9 gongzelong  staff    288 Apr 21  2020 licenses
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 lldb
drwxr-xr-x    7 gongzelong  staff    224 Nov  4 22:47 ndk
drwxr-xr-x@  20 gongzelong  staff    640 Sep 29  2018 ndk-bundle
drwxr-xr-x@   5 gongzelong  staff    160 Dec 15  2016 patcher
**drwxr-xr-x   19 root        wheel    608 Nov 12  2019 platform-tools**
drwxr-xr-x@  16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  33 gongzelong  staff   1056 Feb 17  2020 skins
drwxr-xr-x@  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Nov  3 01:51 sources
drwxr-xr-x@  13 gongzelong  staff    416 Apr  8  2019 system-images
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Feb  4  2018 temp
drwxr-xr-x   15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 26 21:18 tools
```

After executing the command line:

[image: after executing the sudo chown]

```
➜  bin ls -la $ANDROID_HOME/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x@  26 gongzelong  staff    832 Nov  3 01:51 .
drwx------@ 104 gongzelong  staff   3328 Nov  6 17:55 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff  18436 Oct 26 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x    2 gongzelong  staff     64 Nov  4 01:47 .downloadIntermediates
-rw-r--r--    1 gongzelong  staff     16 Nov  6 17:46 .knownPackages
drwxr-xr-x   41 gongzelong  staff   1312 Nov  4 23:08 .temp
-rw-r--r--@   1 gongzelong  staff   1158 Aug 30  2018 SDK Readme.txt
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Aug 29  2016 add-ons
drwxr-xr-x@  34 gongzelong  staff   1088 Nov  3 01:47 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 cmake
drwxr-xr-x@  51 gongzelong  staff   1632 Oct 24  2016 docs
drwxr-xr-x   17 root        wheel    544 Nov 12  2019 emulator
drwxr-xr-x@   8 gongzelong  staff    256 Jul 31  2018 extras
drwxr-xr-x@   3 gongzelong  staff     96 Nov  7  2017 fonts
drwxr-xr-x@   9 gongzelong  staff    288 Apr 21  2020 licenses
drwxr-xr-x@   6 gongzelong  staff    192 Apr 24  2019 lldb
drwxr-xr-x    7 gongzelong  staff    224 Nov  4 22:47 ndk
drwxr-xr-x@  20 gongzelong  staff    640 Sep 29  2018 ndk-bundle
drwxr-xr-x@   5 gongzelong  staff    160 Dec 15  2016 patcher
**drwxr-xr-x   19 gongzelong  wheel    608 Nov 12  2019 platform-tools**
drwxr-xr-x@  16 gongzelong  staff    512 Nov  3 01:47 platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  33 gongzelong  staff   1056 Feb 17  2020 skins
drwxr-xr-x@  14 gongzelong  staff    448 Nov  3 01:51 sources
drwxr-xr-x@  13 gongzelong  staff    416 Apr  8  2019 system-images
drwxr-xr-x@   2 gongzelong  staff     64 Feb  4  2018 temp
drwxr-xr-x   15 gongzelong  staff    480 Oct 26 21:18 tools
```

Then we do the update in SDK management:
[image: Before update]

[image: updaing the sdk 1]

[image: updaing the sdk 2]

[image: update successfully]

before and after install sdk result screenshot

[image: before and after install result screenshot]

**Solution 2:**

Run Android Studio as administration.

`sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 4.1.0.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`

It could also install the android sdk update successfully

[image: before updating]
[image: update successfully]
[image: check and confirm the result]